# Assigning Numeric values to text input

Tags: python

I want to assign a specific integer value to a text type input in python for further indexing.

Example- I input 'sap' as text and i want it to be assigned as 1.

P.s I'm new to coding so spare me for wrong technical terms

Comment: Use a dictionary.

Comment: Mayank is likely correct, but can you elaborate on what you mean by "assign"?

Comment: Share a little more about how you're going to use these assignments later. A `dict` might be a good fit. An `enum` also could be what you're looking for. Hard to know without more context.

Comment: You can't assign numbers to text (if by "text" you mean "a string").

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Two ways:

**1:** You can assign a value to a string with a dictionary, like so:

```
text = input("Input your text: ")
value = int(input(f"Input the value of {text}:"))
d = {text: value}
```

Output:

```
Input your text: hi
Input the value of hi: 6
# {'hi': 6}
```

**2:** Or, if you want to keep the text as a variable:

```
text = input("Input your text: ")
value = int(input(f"Input the value of {text}:"))
locals()[text] = value
```

Output:

```
Input your text: hi
Input the value of hi: 6
# hi = 6
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this via a dict and the below function in example

```
my_index = {}

def add_element(index,el):
    my_index[index] = el

add_element(0,"sap")
add_element(1,"spam")

print(my_index)

OUT: {0: 'sap', 1: 'spam'}
```